# How to calculate the coherence score in topic modeling. (R)

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, lda, topic-modeling

I build the topic models with

```
topicModel <- LDA(DTM, K, method = "Gibbs", control = list(iter = 500, verbose = 25))
```

How to calculate the coherence in this topic modeling?

Can I use the function CalcProbCoherence from package ***textmineR***?

```
CalcProbCoherence(phi, DTM, M = 5)
```

The attributes of my topic model is:

[image]

But what is the phi here?